# Calling a method (stored in a variable) in a closure

Tags: php, closures

I'm trying to find a way to make Example 2 work if possible. Would anyone give me a hand please?

**CALL**

```
$this->getValue('getName');
$this->getValue('getEmail');
```

**EXAMPLE 1 (WORKS)**

```
private function getValue($method)
{
    $o = new Order();
    $p = $o->Payment();

    return $p->$method();                 // Works
    return  $p->call_user_func($method);  // Works
}
```

**EXAMPLE 2 (WON'T WORK)**

```
private function getValue($method)
{
    return
        new Closure(function (Order $o) {
            if ($o->getPayment() instanceof Payment) {
                 return $o->Payment()->$method();                 // Don't Work
                 return $o->Payment()->call_user_func($method);   // Don't Work
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What’s the difference between `$o->getPayment()` and `$o->Payment()`?

Comment: No difference but it can be removed later on so not a problem for now.

Comment: BTW, `Closure`s [disallow](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) direct instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Test {
    public function abc(){
       echo "ok";
    }
}


function getValue($method){
    return (function($o) use ($method) {
        if ($o instanceof Test) {
            return $o->$method();
        }
    });
}

$m = getValue('abc');
$m(new Test());
```

Comment: `use ($method)` sorted it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$o` is undefined i guess, and probably you have received this error message :

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `'&'' or `T_VARIABLE'
```

this should works :

```
private function getValue($method)
{
    return
        new Closure(function () {
            $o = new Order();
            return $o->Payment()->$method();
        });
}
```